# Extend a div tag to the length of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have been searching for an answer to my question, but whatever I try, it doesn't work.

I am trying to create a mock web page for my web design class and am trying to extend the length of a div tag to the length of the page, but auto and 100% does not seem to be working. Unless I specify a pixel height for the div, it stays at 300px, which is too short and does not extend to the bottom of the page.

This is my html:

```
  <div id="nav" align="center">
       <ul>
           <li> Home </li>
           <li> The Council </li>
           <li> Jedi </li>
           <li> The Academy </li>
           <li> Admissions </li>
       <ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content"> <br />

       <button class="subnav" id="contactus"> Contact Us </button>

       <div id="contactus_div"></div>

       <button class="subnav" id="campus"> Life on Campus </button>

       <div id="campus_div"></div>

       <button class="subnav" id="faq"> Frequently Asked Questions </button>

       <div id="faq_div"></div>

       <button class="subnav" id="history"> History of the Jedi Order </button>

       </div id="history_div"></div>

    </div>
```

I need the div with id="content" to span the length of the page. This is the CSS that I have for it:

```
#content {
    background-color:rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.85);
    align:center;   
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 52px;
    left: -2px;
    width:900px;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 40px blue; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px blue; 
    box-shadow:0 0 50px rgb(0, 191, 255);
    z-index:0;
    font-family: arial;
    min-height:100%
}
```

No matter what code I put in there to try and fix it, it ends up coming out as 900px by 300px, unless I change height to a pixel input, which isn't what I want to do. The buttons that I have on the page hide/show div tags using javascript, and I need the page to extend with the showing of the individual div tags.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem. You can't give it a height in `%` unless all its ancestors are having some height either in `%` or in `px`. I don't know why HTML is designed like that but its that way only. You can give height in `px` but not in `%` until the previously mentioned constraint is met.

Answer (score 0):

For the `width` you can use either a pixel number or a percentage, but for the `height` only pixels, you could however use JS/jQuery to do that (get the height of the document or the window and assign it to the div

This will extend the height of the div to the height of the window (the visible part of the page):

```
$(function(){
    $("#content").height($(window).height());
});
```

This will extend the div height ot the height of the document (the height of everything on the page)

```
$(function(){
    $("#content").height($(document).height());
});
```

Comment: I tried both, and it ended up messing with the way my buttons show/hide their div tags. There was unnecessary space after being clicked and the content div didn't adjust with the button divs.

Comment: I cannot see how your examples differ from each other.

Comment: Sorry the second one should have been $(document).height() I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat and set :

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

At the beginning of your css. Then, you can set your `#content` div height with a percentage. Be careful if you set `100%` it will take the height of the entire page, so if your `#nav` take 30%, set your `#content` at 70% (be careful of margins too!).

UPDATE:

I figured out it was possible using tables (the good old tables...), So, take a table with just two lines and make it lake the height of the page `height: 100%`. Then set the first part of you code in the first line and the second one in the second line. Set a `height: 0%` for the first line to adjust it size to the content, the other div will take the rest of the place ! Now you can set a `height: 100%` to the content of the second line to let it take all the free space. Note that you will need the part of code above to set the height of the table.

This is not complete but you can take a look at [**this JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9hB7w/)

I hope this will help you !

Comment: I've tried that. It works at first, but as soon as I click on one of the buttons to show one of the div tags, the content div doesn't adjust with the shown divs.

Comment: Yeah sadly the css is not adjusting itself in case of interactions... The only way I see is to do that in jQuery. Set your height when the document is ready, the update it each time you click on one of your button.

Comment: I made an update with an example using tables. I can't try it for your case but I hope it will be useful =D.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`VW`](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css-viewport-units/) units (not widely supported)
so `100vw` equals `100% of view port width`.
but, I wouldn't recommend you to use it, instead, you should use normal `%` units and build a smarter layout.

Answer (score -1):

Change the following

```
width:900px;
```

To

```
width:100%;
```